# Pip inside virtual environment throws error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I am using virtual environment in python. When I use pip list command or any command to install packages it throws an error.

```
from pip._internal.distributions import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.distributions'
```

When I check the version `pip -V` inside *venv* it shows the version of pip (i.e. no error, working great). But, it is not working in any other commands. Please ask if I did not make it clear. 
Thank you!!!

EDIT:-
I am using Windows 10 Pro. I installed python from their official website of version `3.8.1` using the windows installer. And, my pip version is `20.0.2` I installed pip by adding get-pip.py in bin file. I think there should not be any problem.

Comment: I have already seen that forum, and sadly that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you include your operating system and how you installed python and pip? You may have more luck finding somebody who has done the same thing as you.

Comment: In your venv, type `which pip` or `where pip` to see which pip you are actually running. It should be in your venv directory.

Comment: ```which pip``` didn't get recognized ```where pip``` gives two line input. One with the  path of *pip.exe* inside *venv* and another for the same outside of venv, where I kept my python files.

Comment: `which pip` is for linux. It looks like you are running the correct pip, and I am puzzled by the problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any specific reason you installed pip via get-pip.py and not using the one comes with default installation? There is a warning message on https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ which says get-pip.py can cause problems if you use it alongside pip provided by installation package.